# there is no info about map function?(not Map)

Tags: javascript

i had problem with map function that return integer i had no idea what is this map function or what is its operations and when i search all i find is Map object (Array.prototype.map()) that need array./// to access it but this function does not need object or variable to be access so what on earth is this map function? i have feeling that it is do some sort of fittness/maxfittness

edit : actually it do fittness/maxfittness 
now my question is how my engine know that map that does not exist even if i use ctrl + space do that and when i do or i try alert(map.toString()); to see source code it return native code this mean it does exist why all this mass ?

you can check it in the example on this [link](https://github.com/nature-of-code/noc-examples-p5.js/tree/master/chp09_ga/NOC_9_01_GA_Shakespeare) you will find it in Population.js class because it does not make sense to me

```
naturalSelection() {
// Clear the ArrayList
this.matingPool = [];

let maxFitness = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < this.population.length; i++) {
  if (this.population[i].fitness > maxFitness) {
    maxFitness = this.population[i].fitness;
  }
}

// Based on fitness, each member will get added to the mating pool a certain number of times
// a higher fitness = more entries to mating pool = more likely to be picked as a parent
// a lower fitness = fewer entries to mating pool = less likely to be picked as a parent
for (let i = 0; i < this.population.length; i++) {
   alert(map.toString());
 =>: let fitness = map(this.population[i].fitness, 0, maxFitness, 0,1);

  let n = floor(fitness * 100); // Arbitrary multiplier, we can also use monte carlo method
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) { // and pick two random numbers
    this.matingPool.push(this.population[i]);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: it's a user-land function, so we can't speculate on where it came from, but it appear to be used the same way as [ardunio's map() command](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/): translating one range to another.

Comment: There is no global `map` function in JS. Please show us where the variable is declared.

Comment: The file you linked seems to use the processing.js library, maybe it does define it?

Comment: I will check it

Comment: It might be there ... But why when I use Ctrl + space it doesn't show it and it's description... But it is the only file included by that instructor so it actually the only logical explanation , thanks I was just search for genetic algorithm so I am not too familiar with js